# Как реализовать масштабирование объекта в делфи мышкой?

Tags: delphi

Т.е как это делается в пеинте, фотошопе, и т.д. Выделяем объект, наводим на его верхний угол мышкой, и появляются стрелочки для масштабирования/перемещения и т.д. Хотя б на примере объкта Shape. Хочу попытаться, хотя б для себя сделать планировщик помещений, вид сверху.

Comment: Кстати, был уже подобный вопрос, правда больше по WinAPI, но возможно будет полезно: [Растяжение сторон прямоугольника][1]

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/45434/растяжение-сторон-прямоугольника

Answer (score 2):

Масштабирование перетаскиванием за правый, нижний края или за правый-нижний угол:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Shape1: TShape;
    procedure Shape1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Shape1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Shape1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  dx,dy: integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dx := -1;
  dy := -1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  // При нажатии кнопки мыши на краю фигуры запоминаем расстояние от курсора до границы фигуры
  if X>Shape1.Width-8 then dx := Shape1.Width - X;
  if Y>Shape1.Height-8 then dy := Shape1.Height - Y;
end;

procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var n:integer;
begin
  // Изменение вида курсора на границе фигуры
  n := 0;
  if X>Shape1.Width-8  then n := n + 1;
  if Y>Shape1.Height-8 then n := n + 2;
  case n of
    0: Shape1.Cursor := crDefault;
    1: Shape1.Cursor := crSizeWE;
    2: Shape1.Cursor := crSizeNS;
    3: Shape1.Cursor := crSizeNWSE;
  end;

  // Изменение размера фигуры
  if dx >= 0 then Shape1.Width  := X + dx;
  if dy >= 0 then Shape1.Height := Y + dy;
end;

procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  // При отпускании кнопки мыши "отпускаем" край фигуры
  dx := -1;
  dy := -1;
end;

end.
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, опыт не велик, не мог слаженно сообразить)
Правда почему-то размер изменялся и без щелчка, но добавил переменную, чтоб на моус довн а=1, и тогда на движение проверял условие, и соотв на отпускание возвращаю 0 =)))
Пусть и по ламерски, но зрабаотало норм))) спасибо!

Comment: Чтобы размер не изменялся без щелчка, нужно dx и dy инициализировать
<pre>procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dx := -1;
  dy := -1;
end;</pre>